# How to display a  Form Screen on LWUIT Tabs?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, nokia

I have list items on form, I have to display that form on tabs, when the user clicked on a tab.

How to add that form to tab, after `form.show()` or before?

I need to display first tab as default with Form Screen?

Comment: [Example](https://projects.developer.nokia.com/LWUIT_for_Series_40/browser/Apps/untested-examples/LWUITDemo/src/com/sun/lwuit/uidemo/TabsDemo.java?rev=f2e9efee6949eb4f487bbf37fc93efd863fef9b7) might be helpful for you :)

Comment: But those all are to disaplay  Normal Components on tab,but i want to display a form scren with List Items?

Comment: List & Tab both are different thing, look at your question, where you have mentioned List Items ?

Comment: then ask your question properly in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display form in Tabs. Form is also a component.

```
Form frmObj = new Form("Tabs Example");
Form frmOne = new Form("One");
Form frmTwo = new Form("Two");

Tabs tabObj = new Tabs();
tabObj.addTab("Form One",frmOne);
tabObj.addTab("Form Two",frmTwo );
frmObj.addComponent(tabObj);
frmObj.show();
```

Comment: when should i add my form to tabobj,after finishing lines of code and  form.show() or if we add before that also ,it will work?

Comment: You shouldn't add a form to another form unless you REALLY know what you are doing! Its very bad practice! You need to use a container for the entries.

Comment: Hi Shai Almog,can you answer my question?i need to add my Forms having list of items to the Tabs,First Tab Should Display default FormScreen and from Second Tab onwords we need to display Form Screen,when the user Clicked on Tabs?