# Adding Form to Tabs in LWUIT

Tags: tabs, lwuit

Is it possible to add Form to Tabs Class in LWUIT ?? As per the API tabs contain method to add only component. If yes please provide a sample code how to add it..

Will it be like - new Tabs.addTab("Title", form.show()) or how it is ??

Comment: Please, the next time take a look on the answers forum.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a container for the entries, you can add your form to a tabPane and than add the tabPane to another form(this form is a container for the entries).
do like this:

```
Tabs tabPane = new Tabs(); 
Form frm_Obj = new Form("Show this form");
Form frm1 = new Form("Add this form to tabPane");

tabPane.addTab("My Form",frm1);

frm_Obj.addComponent(tabPane);
frm_Obj.show();
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for it. Where is the show() method of frm1 called ??Unless i call show() its not seen.. If i add as tabPane.addTab("My Form",frm1.show()); it is compile time error.

Comment: you don't need call frm1.show(). when you switch between tabs frm1 will be show in that tab is content it.

Comment: My frm1 is a separate java file which is Customised Form which extends Form but calling my customised form (new CustomisedForm()) is not working...

Comment: It does not matter, it should work. Did you test your CustomisedForm(in other project or etc)? In other projects it is working properly? if it works, put your code(where you customized).

Comment: My customised Form is working well. I called in MIDLET as new CustomisedForm.show(); and it is working. If i place only new CustomisedForm it is not working.

Comment: This is the Exception i am getting when i directly call the instance of my Customised Form while adding it to a tab : Java.lang.IllegalArguementException: A Form cannot be added to a Container at com.sun.lwuit.Container.insertComponentAt: void insertComponentAt(int,com.sun.lwuit.Component) (Container.java :268)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on these posts. You can find here how to create tabs using `Form`. The Form class is a `Component`too.

[StackOverflow tab answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862237/how-to-display-a-form-screen-on-lwuit-tabs)

[Nokia developer tabs answer](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php/222750-Tabbed-pane-in-lwuit)